# General topology by Bourbaki

Tags: general-topology, book-recommendation

I have taken a first course in general topology (first four chapters of Munkres's Topology), now I want to learn more general topology.

I heard Topology by Bourbaki is very good but it also needs lots of set theory. So my question is:

Is the first chapter of Munkres on set theory enough to study Bourbaki?

Comment: I would instead recommend the book by [James Dugundji](http://www.amazon.com/Topology-James-Dugundji/dp/0697068897), which is excellent. You can start reading this book immediately.

Comment: I would not recommend Bourbaki as a textbook to my worst enemy. Dugundji, recommend by @Dietrich, is a fine book, but I don’t consider it any more advanced in its overall coverage than Munkres; it just has a somewhat different orientation and flavor. The book that I would recommend as the next step up is Stephen Willard’s [*General Topology*](http://www.amazon.com/General-Topology-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486434796), which is available in an inexpensive Dover edition and even as an ebook.

Comment: I am sorry but can you @ Brian M. Scott be bit more explicit about not using Bourbaki as text? Because I heard Bourbaki is a great book. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Brian M. scott

Comment: @kevin: I find Bourbaki very heavy-handed and rather idiosyncratic in many respects. If one already knows a fair bit of topology it can be a useful reference, but it’s not at all user-friendly.